# how to add files to a repo wihout being synchronized by Pull Request / Merge?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Main use case is local test configuration files like CI files.
Adding to .gitgnore, does not solve the solution when testing on another server.

One solution is :
   Keep a template version.
   Create a copy of template with unique file name, each user being different.

Another is to prevent git merging with another branch at the merge time.
(ie ignore merge).

Just wondering best practices to manage CI config files in a repo.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by adding to repo but not synchronizing. Can you rephrase your question and provide some examples to make it more clear?

Comment: What kind of files are you looking to exclude? Maybe there is another way to think about solving this issue.

Comment: In fact you could have a template version. You could have a `Makefile` or some _installation script_ which copies that template file to some place outside the repository or to some _.gitignored_ folder within the repository. Another option is to allow each user to have their private configuration file by adding some suffix to the filename (like the hostname).

Comment: Local files (as in related to your own system) should be .gitignored, CI configuration files should be committed to the repository. This is the standard practice and it works well.